# Servicing a bike left in a garage

Tags: maintenance

Knowing next to nothing about bikes I bought a Parva hybrid bike a few years ago, which saw only a few rides before being put in the garage to collect dust. Now that I'm moving to a new city I need to get it back into working condition.

Is it worth taking it to a bike shop (halfords is near) for a service or is it likely that I can do most of the work myself using some sort of guide?

Cheers

Comment: If you take it to a bike shop, take it to a proper one, rather than Halfords.

Comment: are you going to take it with you and ride it? or are you selling it before you go?

Comment: The main hazard is that it's been bumped by a car, bending the frame or warping a wheel.  Beyond that, petroleum vapors are bad for tire rubber.

Comment: @David Richerby why shouldn't a bike be taken to Halfords?

Comment: @DanK It's a bit hit and miss depending which store you go to, but they have a long standing (and not undeserved) reputation for being inept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bicycle maintenance is well within the scope of most people with basic tools. Your task is made easier because the bike had not been ridden many miles before being stored, so it should not have any significant wear and should still be adjusted correctly. Bicycles don't wear out or go out of adjustment when they are just sitting in a garage.

You can go through a basic list of checks then if you find a problem look further guidance here or from other resources.

- I always recommend cleaning the bike thoroughly including the sprockets and chain as it makes maintenance more pleasant and is a chance to visually inspect the bike.
- Inflate tires to recommended pressure. A puncture will be readily evident (although check the next day for slow leak). Tires or tubes may be dried out and cracked. If so you can replace them.
- Check that both brakes are working properly.
- With the rear wheel off the ground manually spin the cranks and change through the gears (getting someone to help you makes this much easier). Spin the wheels, cranks and pedals and make sure they rotate freely with no looseness or play in the bearings.
- Make sure shift and brake cable housings are inserted properly into shifters and derailleurs, levers and calipers, and attachments points on the frame.
- Go over the whole bike making sure everything is attached properly and not loose. Seatpost, seat, handlebars, stem, pedals, brake levers and calipers, shifters, derailleurs etc,
- Make sure wheel quick releases are done up properly.
- Re-lubricate the chain.

Update, some links to Park Tool Company pages on the most likely adjustments you may need to make:

[Front derailleur adjustment](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment)

[Rear derailleur adjustment](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment)

[V-Brake setup](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/linear-pull-brake-service)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I had never actually gotten it adjusted properly after purchase, is this still worth doing?

Comment: @TomClayton yes, if you are willing to spend a little time finding out how to do basic adjustments and going through a bit of a learning curve. There are many great resources on the Web for learning bike maintenance. I edited my answer with links to resources for brakes and gears.

Answer (score 2):

Most bike maintenance is quite straight forward if you have to tools and know what you are doing.

If the bike has not been used much and has been in a relatively dry environment in the garage, then it shouldn't need much to get it going again.

Check the tyres for cracks in the sidewall and/or the rubber compound being hard/brittle - they will need replacing if this is the case.

Check the chain for rust, but assuming it isn't too bad, should be easy to clean up and re-lube following a guide online.

Check the brakes work (and check the brake cables for rust).

Check the gears change (and check the cables for rust).

If you find yourself in the position where the chain/cables/brakes need replacing, its probably best to have a shop do it until you are more familiar with maintenance.  Otherwise, you should be able to do it all yourself.